# Query to arrays

Tags: arrays, coldfusion-10

I have the following query set:

```
        ID  SERVICEID   DURATION
        1   1           30
        2   1           60
        3   1           90
        4   1           120
        8   2           30
        7   2           60
        6   2           90
        5   2           120
        9   3           30
        10  3           60
        11  3           90
        13  4           30
        12  4           60
        14  5           30
        15  5           60
        16  5           90
        17  6           30
        19  7           30
        18  7           60
        20  8           30
        21  9           30
        22  10          30
        23  11          60
        24  12          60
        25  13          30
```

I need some sort of a set of arrays like this:
ARRAY[SERVICEID] = [DURATION1, DURATION2, DURATION N]

```
        ARRAY[1] = [30, 60, 90, 120]
        ...
        ARRAY[4] = [30, 60]
        ...
        ARRAY[12] = [60]
        etc..
```

Comment: So what issue are you having? Also, realize if there are gaps in the service id values, the array will contain gaps as well.

Comment: The issue is how to create the array :( And yes, I do realize the gaps in the array... The thing is I need to bring this query results in useful form to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, using Structure instead of Arrays:

```
    <cfset durStruct = {} >
    <cfloop query="durations">
      <cfif NOT StructKeyExists(durStruct,serviceid)>
        <cfset durStruct[serviceid] = [] >
      </cfif>
      <cfset ArrayAppend(durStruct[serviceid],duration) > 
    </cfloop>
```

And then in Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            <cfoutput>let durData = #serializeJson(durStruct)#;</cfoutput>
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to encode chars like single quotes which will break the javascript.  I don't recall offhand what functions CF10 has, but later versions have encodeForJavascript().